# Ruby - If element in array contains a certain character, return the associated element(s)

Tags: ruby, arrays, character, contains, element

Example:

```
my_array = ['2823BII','4A','76B','10J']
```

[using magical method delete_if_doesnt_contain()]

```
my_array.map! do |elements|
    elements.delete_if_doesnt_contain('A')
end
```

I want that to set `my_array = ['4A']`

Even if I could iterate through an array and just return the index of the element that contains an 'A' I'd be happy.  Thanks for any help!

Thanks for the answers below, but one more question.

```
other_array = ['4']
my_var = other_array.to_s
my_array.select!{|x| x.include?(my_var)}
```

This isn't working for me.  What am I missing?  Something happen when I converted the array to a string?

Comment: do `my_var = other_array[0]`... Now don't update your post with any more question. Ask different one..

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you!  Back on a roll now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very easy using [`#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select) :

```
my_array = ['2823BII','4A','76B','10J']
my_array.select { |str| str.include?('A') }
# => ["4A"]
```

Or if you want to modify the source array, do use the [bang version of select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-select-21) :-

```
my_array.select! { |str| str.include?('A') }
```

Comment: OP may want `.select!` to match question

Comment: @NeilSlater added.. I don't use bang version.. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'm new.  What if I want to pass include a variable?

Comment: Passing include? a variable is moving on. str.include?(my_var) doesn't work, nor does str.include?('#{my_var}')

Comment: @quelleck You can do it.. There is no problem.. `my_array = ['2823BII','4A','76B','10J']
var = 'A'
my_array.select { |str| str.include?(var) }
# => ["4A"]`

Answer (score 0):

Arup's answer is correct.

However, to answer your last question specifically, "iterate through an array and just return the index of the element that contains an 'A'", the "index" method returns the index for a matching element:

```
my_array.index {|x| x.include?('A') }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method is a lot shorter

```
my_array = ['2823BII','4A','76B','10J']
my_array.grep /A/
```